# Python - popup message drawn on the screen

Tags: python, popup, screen, draw

I'm writing a program and I need to inform the user about some changes with a popup message, but not a popup window. Something like the rectangle informing about new message in Kadu - no window, just a bitmap drawn directly on the screen for a few seconds.

I wonder if there is a simple way to do that with win32 package or Tkinter, and handle the event when the user clicks on the rectangle.

Actually the message would be constant, so the bitmap might be loaded from a file, but I still don't know how to start.

Any ideas, please?

Regards, mopsiok

Answer (score 0):

I am using wxPython and looking for a way to have a popup message. Now I am using a popupmenu in which I append each item of the menu with one line of the message.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer to my question. That's my code using Tkinter, hope it will help you.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label
from Image import open as iopen #doesn't needed if you won't display image
from ImageTk import PhotoImage #as before

root = Tk()
img = PhotoImage(iopen("some_path")) #load an image
label = Label(root, image=img)
label.image = img
label.bind("<Button-1>", Click)
label.pack()
root.geometry('-0-40') #place in the right-bottom corner
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1) #popup
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.mainloop()

def Click(event): #close the window if image clicked
    root.destroy()
    print 'window closed'
```